# Logback does not insert data to the database

Tags: java-8, logback

I'm using Logback in a couple of my applications to log errors to the database. Now in my newest application I created the same logging that a normally use. But now the application doesn't log anything to the database.

I'm using source code to add a db appender to the logger. The code looks like:

```
Logger logger = (Logger) LoggerFactory.getLogger("defaultLogger");
LoggerContext lc = (LoggerContext) LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory();

DataSourceConnectionSource source = new DataSourceConnectionSource();
source.setContext(lc);
source.setDataSource(Database.getInstance().getDatasource());

source.start();

DBAppender dbAppender = new DBAppender();
dbAppender.setName("db");
dbAppender.setConnectionSource(source);
dbAppender.setContext(lc);      
dbAppender.start();

logger.addAppender(dbAppender);
logger.setLevel(Level.ALL);
logger.setAdditive(true);
logger.error("test");
```

When I trying the application to use the logback.xml file same behaviour. No logs are written to the database. Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

Something was wrong with the database. I removed the logging tables and created them again with the script of Logback. Now everything is working just fine.